# Must django module django-serverside-datatable module queryset take objects from models.py?

Tags: javascript, python, html, mysql, datatable

I am trying to make a page with django-serverside-datatable and I'm new to the module. I'm trying to make a querySet without objects. all. Is it possible? I'm making simple pages to see the functioning of the Django-serverside-datatable. This is my functional code:

Views.py:

```
class ItemListView(ServerSideDatatableView):
    queryset = Articulos.objects.all()
   
    columns = ['nombre', 'seccion', 'precio']
```

I take these 3 columns from models...
My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mytable').dataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        sAjaxSource: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/",  
                            columns: [
                                {name: "nombre", data: 0},
                                {name: "seccion", data: 1},
                                {name: "precio", data: 2},
                            ],
    });
});
```

This code works perfectly. But, the thing is, I'm using various DataBases and simple objects. all isn't enough. So I'm making an SQL Query, but, maybe it can but Django-serverside-datatables doesn't detect SQLQuerys? Only querySet's? I do the query like this

```
cur = connections['default'].cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT id, nombre, seccion, precio FROM Prueba.baseDatos_articulos")
    llistaArticulos = cur.fetchall()
```

But i cannot find a way to do this I tried these things:

```
class ItemListView(ServerSideDatatableView):
    cur = connections['default'].cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT id, nombre, seccion, precio FROM Prueba.baseDatos_articulos")
    llistaArticulos = cur.fetchall()

    data_dict = []
    for row in llistaArticulos
        data_dict.append({
            'id': row[0],
            'nombre': row[1],
            'seccion': row[2],
            'precio': row[3]
        })
    columns = data_dict
```

```
class ItemListView(ServerSideDatatableView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT id, nombre, seccion, precio FROM Prueba.baseDatos_articulos")

        return CursorQuerySet(cursor)

    columns = ['id','nombre', 'seccion', 'precio']
```

```
class ItemListView(ServerSideDatatableView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        with connections['default'].cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT id, nombre, seccion, precio FROM Prueba.baseDatos_articulos")

            queryset = []
            for row in cursor:
                queryset.append(row)

        return queryset

    columns = ['id','nombre', 'seccion', 'precio']
```

I can't make it work! Is it possible?